# Why is the output different using printf?

Tags: c

In some places the command `printf("%f\n", 5 / 2);` is different. 
Why, and how to fix that?

```
int main()
{
    int a = 65;
    char c = (char)a;
    int m = 3.0/2;
    printf("%c\n", c);              // output: A
    printf("%f\n", (float)a);       // output: 65.000
    printf("%f\n", 5 / 2);          // output: 65.000
    system("PAUSE");
    printf("%f\n", 5.0 / 2);        // output: 2.5000
    printf("%f\n", 5 / 2.0);        // output: 2.5000
    printf("%f\n", (float)5 / 2);   // output: 2.5000
    printf("%f\n", 5 / 2);          // output: 2.5000
    system("PAUSE");
    printf("%f\n", 5 / (float)2);   // output: 2.5000
    printf("%f\n", (float)(5 / 2)); // output: 2.0000
    printf("%f\n", 5 / 2);          // output: 2.0000
    system("PAUSE");
    printf("%f\n", 5.0 / 2);        // output: 2.5000
    printf("%d\n", m);              // output: 1
    printf("%f\n", 5 / 2);          // output: 2.5000


    system("PAUSE");
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: What exactly you want to "fix"?

Comment: I want to "fix" that to its real output and not any other output...

Comment: `5/2` --> `2`.  It is integer math.  That is how integers work in C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`5/2` gives an integer as result, not a floating-point number, and printf cannot automatically convert to another type, as an assignment can. If you compile with GCC, you'll get the warning "format '%f' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 2 has type 'int'". (Yes, double. All floats are converted to doubles before being sent to a variable-argument function like printf.)

The argument you have sent, an integer, doesn't match the format string `%f`. According to the C standard, this will cause what it calls "undefined behaviour", which means that anything can happen. What *typically* happens, though, is that printf will look at the place in memory where the floating-point number would have been, if you had sent one as an argument, and take whatever it finds there and interpret it as a floating-point number. Since a typical `int` is 32 bits, and a typical `double` is 64 bits, printf will take some other data, perhaps the number 65 from a previous call!

To fix the problem, send a floating-point number to printf, for example using `5.0/2`, `(double)5/2` or `2.5` instead of `5/2`.

Comment: OK, but it looks like it output the same output that was line before
and i want to understand why.

Comment: @RuslanVer Could be that a float argument(which first gets promoted to a double) are passed in a floating point register, or in a different place on the stack and that's where printf expects to find the argument you pass to it, and not wherever an int argument is passed to printf. Thus printf extracts a leftover floating point value  when you lied to it and told it you're passing in a floating point, when you actually passed in an int. Since the code yields undefined behaviour, it might not be determistic or reproducabe. If you pass 5/2 (an int),  you must use "%d". not "%f"