# printf output c programming can anybody explain output

Tags: c, printf

c-programming output printf()

Hi guys,

I have a question to following code:
`

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("%f\n", (8/5)/2);
    printf("%f\n", (float) 5/2);
    printf("%f\n", (8/5)/2);
    return 0;
}
```

Line 3 and five are the same. But output isn´t it. Why is that? I have no declaration of variables just `printf()`
Output:

```
0.000000
2.500000
2.500000
```

But if I invert line 4 and 5 then output is same to line 3 as it should be.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("%f\n", (8/5)/2);
    printf("%f\n", (8/5)/2);
    printf("%f\n", (float) 5/2);
    return 0;
}
```

```
0.000000
0.000000
2.500000
```

Can anybody explain the output of this code?

Comment: Please see [Division result is always zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345902/division-result-is-always-zero). It might not be zero here, but integer division happens, and also an `int` is passed where `double` is expected.

Comment: The first and third `printf` statements pass an integer as the parameter. Since the format string says the parameter will be a float you have undefined behavior.

Comment: You're performing integer devision, hence the result is `0`.

Comment: That´s exactly what I want. I want to make an integer division but `float` is expected. Note I have added output to question by inverting line 4 and 5

Comment: The first one could be `printf("%f\n", (8.0 / 5.0) / 2.0);`

Comment: Floating point values are passed in one set of registers; integers in a different set of registers.  Once the floating point register is set to 2.5, the integer arithmetic doesn't change it.  The behaviour is undefined, but that's an explanation of what happens.  Try: `printf("%f %d\n", 355.0/113.0, 355/113); printf("%f %d\n", 355/113, 355.0/113.0);` — given what you're seeing, I expect you to see the same output twice.  (My Mac gives the same answer twice, even though the arguments are reordered.  I also have to avoid my default compilation options — otherwise, it doesn't compile.)

Comment: See also [Why is the output different using `printf()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33766748/15168)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you so much. It makes absolutely sense. The output is same as it is by you and also I understand now why. It seems the undefined behaviour is caused on hardware level with the registers. My question to you. Can you write your comment in an extra answer so I can mark as solved with green symbol than other see directly your right answer to this topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74331197/printf-output-c-programming-can-anybody-explain-output#comment131227812_74331197):

> On machines such as x86/64 architecture, floating point values are passed in one set of registers; integers in a different set of registers. Once the floating point register is set to 2.5, the integer arithmetic doesn't change it. The behaviour is undefined, but that's an explanation of what happens. Try:
>
> ```
> printf("%f %d\n", 355.0/113.0, 355/113);
> printf("%f %d\n", 355/113, 355.0/113.0);
> ```
>
> Given what you're seeing, I expect you to see the same output twice. My Mac gives the same answer twice, even though the arguments are reordered.

Source:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%f %d\n", 355.0/113.0, 355/113);
    printf("%f %d\n", 355/113, 355.0/113.0);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
3.141593 3
3.141593 3
```

> I note that I have to avoid my default compilation options — otherwise, it doesn't compile.

Default compilation:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-common -c fl43.c
fl43.c: In function ‘main’:
fl43.c:6:14: error: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Werror=format=]
    6 |     printf("%f %d\n", 355/113, 355.0/113.0);
      |             ~^        ~~~~~~~
      |              |        |
      |              double   int
      |             %d
fl43.c:6:17: error: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘double’ [-Werror=format=]
    6 |     printf("%f %d\n", 355/113, 355.0/113.0);
      |                ~^              ~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 |                   |
      |                 int                 double
      |                %f
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
$
```

Answer (score 1):

While your code will *compile*, you should receive *warnings* about passing an `int` where a `double` was expected. The result is [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

```
% gcc test.c
test.c:3:20: warning: format specifies type 'double' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
    printf("%f\n", (8/5)/2);
            ~~     ^~~~~~~
            %d
test.c:5:20: warning: format specifies type 'double' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
    printf("%f\n", (8/5)/2);
            ~~     ^~~~~~~
            %d
2 warnings generated.
```

Comment: _Undefined_ behavior is just that: undefined. It can work properly. Or not.

Comment: That´s not undefined behaviour. The `int ` term commits to `%f`. This is okay because `float` has 4 bytes and `int ` too. Just math result is wrong sure but note if you want to commit `double` expression to `int` this execute undefined behaviour cause `double` has 8 bytes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38597274/why-does-printff-0-give-undefined-behavior

Comment: I would clarify "work properly" to "work the way you _expect_". Without a definition for the behavior, there is not really a "proper" way for it to work.

Comment: @hello447, note that `%f` does not mean `float` but `double`! So it *is* Undefined Behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

It is one big undefined behaviour as you pass integer but ask `printf` to print `double`

You need to to cast the result:

```
    printf("%f\n", (double)((8/5)/2));
    printf("%f\n", (double) 5/2);
    printf("%f\n", (double)((8/5)/2));
```